# extract datas from XMLs

Tags: php

managing information technology systems in a business environment

I'm using Konika Bizhub C554
troughout it's IP adress (ie : 195.20.12.1)
I can read an .xml page ([system_counter.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPsdn.jpg))

inspecting the source code, I can easely read all values
embodieded beetween tags **values**

**Question :**
in a self-made PHP code
how can I name thoses **values** ?
such as $values
to target specifics I need to

thoses values must be available in the code source as a table, or just named as php values (ie : $count[$i] )
thoses values belong to

Any hints could be helpfull

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here, you can consider asking them on [so].